# CheckBox don't disable input

Tags: jquery, input, checkbox

I want to change the value of the `input [name = '"+ $ name +"']` to vary the field checkboxs
but it does not work ... why?

```
 $(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    var $name= $(this).attr("name");
    if ($checkbox.prop('checked')) 
    {   
        $("input [name='"+$name+"']").prop('disabled', true);


        $("input [name='"+$name+"']").focus();
    } else {
        $("input [name='"+$name+"']").prop('disabled', false);
    }
})
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML markup too...

Comment: What does *to vary the field checkboxs* mean and in what way *does [it] not work*?

Answer (score 3):

There should be no space here:

```
input [name=
```

like this:

```
input[name=
```

The space means that it will look for an element with that name **inside** of an input.  Without the space it finds an input with that name.

Comment: there is no white space between [''] "$ name" contains the name of the checkbox to detect the input with the same name

Comment: There is a space between `input` and `[]`.  remove it.